# Applying class to only the active nav item, workaround for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a site where I'm using bootstrap, but I'm actually trying to apply a custom style to active nav items (more of a backdrop rather than just text color)

However, in order to get started and test things I'm just using the white text color to get it working and I have no luck so far.

I've included the JS, but basically I'm trying to apply a class to the span tag within the nav item (li) link (a) for any active item.

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I've applied an empty span to each line item link which is where I want the class to go for the active item

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link')
            .click(function (e) {
        $('ul.navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link > span')
            .removeClass('active-pill');
        $(this).addClass('active-pill');
    });
});
```

```css
a.active-pill{
    color: white;
}
.nav-link{
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">    
        
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="active-pill">Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span>FAQs</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just make the selector more specific it should work.

```
a.active-pill{color: white}
```

Bases on running it locally it seems that the color from the .nav-link takes priority so being for specific will fix that.

Comment: It seems like that wants to work but when the page for the clicked item loads, the home item is still active

Comment: Interesting, it seems that the embedded snippet partially works but the class isn't getting removed. Just added

Comment: It looks like it works for a split second but when the new page loads after the link click, it reverts back to home

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you issue is when things get loaded. so maybe try using this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $('ul.navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link')
            .click(function (e) {
        $('ul.navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a.nav-link > span')
            .removeClass('active-pill');
        $(this).addClass('active-pill');
    });
};
```

window.onload happens later after everything is loaded and might solve the issue